# How to change tasks amount uploaded from bug tracker in Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, task-management

Are there any possibility to set up the number of tasks uploaded from redmine into idea's task management system?

My problem is that idea uploads only 25 latest issues by default after i press `Ctrl+Space` in *Open Task* dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible right now, please [vote for the open request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-82058) in YouTrack.